# App Store: Binary Rejected; Missing demo account information

Tags: app-store, testflight

I´m in the process of uploading my second app for TestFlight. The first time went well, but this time it got rejected.

> > We have started the review of your beta app, but we are not able to continue because we need a demo account to fully assess your app
> >     features.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide a user
>   name and password in the Beta App Review Information section for your
>   app in App Store Connect. Please be sure to include content in your
>   app that demonstrates the features and functionality available in your
>   app.
>
> To provide demo account information:
>
> - Log in to App Store Connect
> - Click on "My Apps"
> - Select your app
> - Select “Test Information”
> - Scroll down to “Beta App Review Information”
> - Select the "A demo account is required to use all the features of the app" box
> - Enter demo credentials in the "User name" and "Password" fields
> - Click “Save”
> - Scroll up to “Builds” section and submit a new binary for review

I don't have "A demo account is required to use all the features of the app" box. I only have "Sign-in required" box:

[image: Screenshot from TestFight]

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Make sure This demo account is still working in your app after that upload app again.

Comment: So, when they ask for a demo account, they mean the Sign-in I already provided? (Test@mail.com / test123) Do I need to upload everything again?

Answer (score 0):

> We have started the review of your beta app, but we are not able to continue because **we need a demo account to fully accesses your app features.**

They clearly told you where the issue manifests itself.

### They need:

> - A working demo account.
> - A demo account that "fully" accesses your app functionalities.

Happened to me once. Please test the account and the app again. Since we can't access or test anything here. A precise solution won't be given

Comment: I'm aware that they need a working demo account. But when they say "Select the "A demo account is required to use all the features of the app" box", and I have no such thing I get confused. I'm certain that the test user I already provided is fully functional.

Comment: @Catch that’s the “sign in required” check box. It’s actually confusing though